# How to configure the security group on AWS to run node app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, ip

AWS is new to me. I want to configure three VM on AWS to run one node.js app.
I want to set three VMs to run MongoDB, Memcached and node seperatedly.
The question description says that You
  should also carefully configure the security groups inside of AWS, so that *only* your node instance can access your mongo and mcd instances, and so that your node instance is only reachable on port 8080.

When I am setting the security group, I feel really confused. If somebody can tell me how to configure this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PS: I wanted to comment to OP's question, but I can't as I don't have enough reputation.

You need to go through some docs on AWS to understand this. If you are building enterprise level app you want to look into this [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ug.pdf) where you can get more info on security groups and how you can setup your architecture on AWS with security.

Secondly, Security groups are the rules which are applied on instance level - consider as firewall, for your system more info [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Security.html). In your case you can open node.js ports for mongodb (27017/18 TCP) and Memcached (11211 - TCP) instances as node only requires to connect to mongodb and memcached, also you can setup NAT if you want to keep your instances in private subnet.